# Updating values in CSV file using awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have a CSV file, and i need to write a script using `awk` command and i need some help with it.
For each **odd** column (except the first one), if value is equal to 0, then the value from the left need to be zero as well.

Input:

```
1,1,0,1,1,1,0
2,3,4,0,3,2,1
3,3,0,3,5,7,6
3,6,6,7,0,8,4
```

Output:

```
1,0,0,1,1,0,0
2,3,4,0,3,2,1
3,0,0,3,5,7,6
3,6,6,0,0,8,4
```

Can someone help me with the command?

Comment: @Bhush_Techidiot  : Read all of Omri 's CSV based questions. Omri : Why are you asking this again?

Comment: @shellter I have a basic knowledge with these commands, and it was a super-urgent need. Hope to find the time to learn it step by step, and to improve my abilities. Anyway, my questions and the answers i got, are good for other users for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk command should work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=2) if ($i==0) $(i-1)=0} 1' file
1,0,0,1,1,0,0
2,3,4,0,3,2,1
3,0,0,3,5,7,6
3,6,6,0,0,8,4
```

`for (i=3; i<=NF; i+=2)` will iterate the odd numbered field list starting from field #3 and set the previous field to `0` if current is `0`.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!